# Int list returned by LINQ query

Tags: linq

I have one table having ID and other attributes.

How can I get **list of int** of IDs by LINQ query on that table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the Select method to project your result into a different format:

```
var myList = myTable.Select(t => t.ID).ToList();
```

That should do it, note you can also use the more SQL-like syntax:

```
var myList = (from t in myTable
             select t.ID).ToList();
```

EDIT:

Also note, this is C# syntax, if you want a different syntax you need to clarify which language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var list = from b 
           in MyDataContext.Table
           select b.ID
```

Comment: This will return IEnumberable<int>, not List<int> - although theres a good chance that the question holder doesn't care.